# Webpack HMR appears to work, however, I see this error in the terminal -- any ideas?

Tags: express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

So, I have a webpack server running on port 3001 and express running on port 3000. All request to webpack server are being proxied to the express server. Everything "appears" to be working, however, I continue seeing this error message (as if it's continually trying to connect) in the terminal. Any ideas?

```
Error: Cannot GET /122620bb0d13d4e53109.hot-update.json

Error: Cannot GET /__webpack_hmr

at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:15:17)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at SendStream.error (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:120:7)
at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
at SendStream.emit (events.js:182:7)
at SendStream.error (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:245:17)
Error: Cannot GET /__webpack_hmr
at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:15:17)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at SendStream.error (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:120:7)
at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
at SendStream.emit (events.js:182:7)
at SendStream.error (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:245:17)
```

Here's my webpack dev server:

```
import chalk from 'chalk';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import env from '../config/env';
import WebpackDevServer from 'webpack-dev-server';
import webpackConfig from './webpack.config.development.js';

const server = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(webpackConfig), {
  publicPath: '/dist',
  contentBase: '/client',
  inline: true,
  hot: true,
  compress: true,
  stats: false,
  quiet: true,
  noInfo: true,
  lazy: false,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With'
  },
  proxy: {
    "*": 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
});

server.listen(env.WEBPACK_PORT, 'localhost', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(chalk.red(err));
  }
  console.log(chalk.yellow(`Webpack server listening on http://localhost:${env.WEBPACK_PORT}`));
});
```

and the webpack.config.development.js

```
{
  "target": "web",
  "entry": [
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3001",
    "webpack/hot/dev-server",
    "babel-polyfill",
    "./client/index"
  ],
  "output": {
    "path": "/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT/dist",
    "filename": "bundle.js"
  },
  "resolve": {
    "root": "/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/PROJECT",
    "modulesDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "client"
    ],
    "extensions": [
      "",
      ".json",
      ".js"
    ]
  }
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems to be working now. The webpack dev config needed the matching publicPath

```
publicPath: `http://localhost:${env.WEBPACK_PORT}/dist`,
```